# How can I center an image to the middle of the page and resize it if it's bigger than the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to resize an image and keep it in the middle of the page.
I have tried `<center>` and `align="middle"` and many other things I've found on here that didn't help.
Here is an example of the page (How I want it to be but without the text, background etc):

https://gyazo.com/5943303da90127d4e5bf24989812888e

And here is how it is currently:

- Small Image: http://i.inf.vg/qkYCd
- Medium Image: http://i.inf.vg/3AtgG
- Large Image: http://i.inf.vg/E6b0r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
img {
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   max-height: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<img src="//i.imgur.com/7xYQq8P.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.container .inner {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="http://i.inf.vg/images/png/3AtgG.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

You could use media queries to change the image on different sized devices.

codepen: http://codepen.io/pen/